# How to use border with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border

How can I solve this problem?
When you add borders to a div, the div is not centered and
the `span12` class is not centered.

I would like to center the div with the borders

```
<div class="row" >
   <div class="span12" style="border: 2px solid black">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span4">
            1
         </div>
         <div class="span4">
            2
         </div>
         <div class="span4">
            3
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 77):

Unfortunately, that's what borders do, they're counted as part of the space an element takes up.  Allow me to introduce border's less commonly known cousin:  `outline`.  It is virtually identical to border.  Only difference is that it behaves more like box-shadow in that it doesn't take up space in your layout and it has to be on all 4 sides of the element.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/wyktr

```
.foo {
    outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 44):

As of Bootstrap 3, you can use Panel classes:

`<div class="panel panel-default">Surrounded by border</div>`

In Bootstrap 4, you can use Border classes:

`<div class="border border-secondary">Surrounded by border</div>`

Comment: Heads up - they dropped panels in Bootsrap 4 .  Now use card:    see https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/    and https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

Answer (score 17):

There's a property in CSS called `box-sizing.` It determines the total width of an element on your page. The default value is `content-box`, which doesn't include the padding, margin, or border of the element.

Hence, if you set a `div` to have `width: 500px` and `20px` padding all around, it will take up `540px` on your website (500 + 20 + 20).

This is what is causing your problem. Bootstrap calculates set widths for things just like the above example, and these things don't have borders. Since Bootstrap fits together like a puzzle, adding a border to one of the sides would yield a total width of 501px (continuing the above example) and break your layout.

The easiest way to fix this is to adjust your `box-sizing`. The value you would use is `box-sizing: border-box`. This includes the padding *and* border in your box elements. [You can read more about box-sizing here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)

A problem with this solution is that it only works on IE8+. Consequently, if you need deeper IE support you'll need to override the Bootstrap widths to account for your border.

To give an example of how to calculate a new width, begin by checking the width that Bootstrap sets on your element. Let's say it's a `span6` and has a width of `320px` (this is purely hypothetical, the actual width of your span6 will depend on your specific configuration of Bootstrap). If you wanted to add a single border on the right hand side with a 20px padding over there, you'd write this CSS in your stylesheet

```
.span6 {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 299px;
 }
```

where the new width is calculated by:

`old width - padding - border`

Comment: "...it will take up 540px on your website". Did you mean webpage? Hehe +1 regardless

Answer (score 9):

Depending what size you want your `div` to be, you could utilize Bootstrap's built-in component `thumbnail` class, along with (or without) the grid system to create borders around each of your `div` items.

**[These examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails) on Bootstrap's website demonstrates the ease-of-use and lack of need for any special additional `CSS`:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**which produces the following `div` grid items:**

[image: Simple grid objects]

**or add some additional content:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**which produces the following `div` grid items:**

[image: Custom grid objects]

Comment: Using your example of `thumbnail` I was able to create simple borders for `div` tag. My upvote.

Answer (score 7):

What others have mentioned about border vs border box is definitely correct. You can still get this to work without having to create any custom classes though: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/yfzdD/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="span12">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span4"> 1 </div>
        <div class="span4"> 2 </div>
        <div class="span4"> 3 </div>
        </div><!-- end nested row -->
    </div><!-- end span 12 -->

</div> <!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.span12{
border:solid 2px black;
background-color:grey;  
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

While it's probably not the *correct* way to do it, something that I've found to be a simple workaround is to simply use a box-shadow rather than a border... This doesn't break the grid system. For example, in your case:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.span12{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77Udx/1/)

Comment: Box-shadow borders are definitely pretty neat, but I don't see why you'd choose to use this over box-sizing in this case. Box-sizing is not only the correct way to do it, but it also has deeper browser support. Box-shadow shadows seem to be useful if you're looking to add multiple borders without additional mark-up, but, for me, I'd probably avoid using them here!

Comment: I didn't say I'd choose them over box-size... Just said it was a very simple workaround. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't just add a border to the span because it will break the layout because of the way width is calculate: width = border + padding + width. Since the container is 940px and the span is 940px, adding 2px border (so 4px altogether) will make it look off centered. The work around is to change the width to include the 4px border (original - 4px) or have another div inside that creates the 2px border.

Comment: There's no need for a workaround given a DOM restructure or use of `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a basic border around you just need to use bootstrap wells.

For example the code below:

```
<div class="well">Basic Well</div>
```

Comment: I found this particularly useful for Shiny, where Bootstrap 4 isn't available yet; `panel` is okay, but it looks bad within a sidebar or other well, with its white background. Just using another well is ideal for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 and higher try this to put borders around your empty divs use `border border-primary` here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="row border border-primary">
        <div class="col border border-primary">logo</div>
        <div class="col border border-primary">navbar</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the link to the border utility in Bootstrap 4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/borders/