# CSS add a fat "frame" around an IMG without changing IMG positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have rows of thumbnails in a `<div>` with only a `small margin/border/padding set`. I'd like to add a `'focus'` class to highlight one thumbnail on the page during a CSS transition, i.e. `'div.thumb.focus'`

Is there any easy CSS Trick to wrap a frame around the `'div.thumb'` WITHOUT re-positioning the `div.thumb` in the page?

The div.thumbs are all absolutely positioned within a container. And I want the frame to be THICKER than the `margin/padding` between `div.thumb`. It can live on a higher `z-index`, and partially cover neighboring thumbs, as long as the click events read the `div.thumb.focus`.  An easy JQuery solution is acceptable.

```
 // using LESS syntax
.container {
   position: relative;

  .thumb {
    &.focus {
       <need help here>
    }
    top: @top;
    left: @left;
    position: absolute;
    margin: @margin;
    padding: @padding;

    img {
      width: @width;
      height: @height;
    }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Try `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px red`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use border with Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328679/how-to-use-border-with-bootstrap)

Comment: try outline, doesn't change element dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few solutions come to mind (not Bootstrap specific):

Using a better box model, but it may affect your padding:

```
box-sizing: border-box
border: 10px solid red
```

Or using an hard inset shadow that'll look like a border:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px red
```

You could use an outline but it would overflow outside the box without affecting its dimensions:

```
outline: 10px solid red
```

Comment: outline is what I'm looking for. I can minimize the spacing between thumbnails and still have an easily visible "frame".  Extra Credit: In the case of a thumbnail on an edge, is there an easy way for the outline to extend BEYOND the enclosing container?

Comment: figured that one out. used overflow:visible on the container

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not too familiar with LESS, so I've just done this in regular CSS.

There are a few options you could choose.

**Add a Negative Margin**

```
.thumb.focus{
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

This may not be suitable for your case, however, as you already have a margin set. It may be useful for others though.

**Add a Shadow**

```
.thumb.focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px blue; //use inset if you want it inside the thumb
}
```

This could work well, but not if you want multiple colours/thicknesses on some sides.

**Use box-sizing**

```
.thumb.focus{    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

The main problem with this would be browser support.

**Use Outline**

```
.thumb.focus{
    outline: 4px solid blue;
}
```

This has a similar issue to the box shadow I believe.