# Image grid (Bootstrap) and compensating for margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following grid - http://codepen.io/vmpen/pen/GqrXQz where aspect ratios must be preserved, whilst being responsive. With no padding
the grid behaves correctly.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-3 grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="text-center feature feature--full col-xs-12">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/1080x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center feature feature--width2 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="img-wrapper height2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/540x540"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper height2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x540"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 feature">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/270x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 feature feature--width2">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/540x270"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 feature feature--width3 feature--width3">
      <div class="img-wrapper last"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/810x270"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When items are padded the height of images do not compensate for the padding, making the grid misaligned.

I have managed to fix this with setting a fixed height but that breaks the responsiveness of the grid and aspect ratios. Can someone point me to some well established techniques to solve this problem. As a final point I have tried various masonry solutions to no avail. My problem is quite similar to this - https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/877

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer - [How to use border with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328679/how-to-use-border-with-bootstrap)

`outline: #fff solid 10px;`

It provides the same affect for borders around the image but isn't calculated by the browser when rendering containers.